# Code example of how to pro-rate Fixed Calendar Year Membership in CiviCRM

Tags: civimember

To avoid having members pay full price for a fixed Membership Type Plan? We are using the rollover but need something that kicks in before the complete rollover takes affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the buildAmount hook - (in a custom extension) - very similar to how CiviDiscount works! July 01 is the roll over day. After that we don't need to discount anymore. This is my first pass at it:

```
function membershippro_civicrm_buildAmount($pageType, &$form, &$amounts) {

  //retrieve price set field associated with this priceset
  $priceSetInfo = CRM_CiviDiscount_Utils::getPriceSetsInfo($psid);
  $originalAmounts = $amounts;

  $discountApplied = FALSE;
    foreach ($amounts as $fee_id => &$fee) {
    if (!is_array($fee['options'])) {
      continue;
    }

  foreach ($fee['options'] as $option_id => &$option) {
    $originalLabel = $originalAmounts[$fee_id]['options'][$option_id]['label'];
    $originalAmount = CRM_Utils_Rule::cleanMoney($originalAmounts[$fee_id]['options'][$option_id]['amount']);

    $now = time(); // or your date as well
    $to_date = strtotime("2017-07-01");
    $datediff = $to_date - $now;

    $num_days = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

    if ($num_days >= 1) {
      $discountAmount = $originalAmounts[$fee_id]['options'][$option_id]['amount'] * $num_days / 365;
    }

    $amount = $originalAmount - $discountAmount;

    $option['amount'] = $amount;
    $option['discount_applied'] = $discountAmount;

    $recalculateTaxAmount = array();
    if (array_key_exists('tax_amount', $originalAmounts[$fee_id]['options'][$option_id]) &&
      array_key_exists('tax_rate', $originalAmounts[$fee_id]['options'][$option_id])
    ) {
      $recalculateTaxAmount = CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution_Utils::calculateTaxAmount($amount, $originalAmounts[$fee_id]['options'][$option_id]['tax_rate']);
        if (!empty($recalculateTaxAmount)) {
          $option['tax_amount'] = round($recalculateTaxAmount['tax_amount'], 2);
        }
      }

        $discountApplied = TRUE;

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this looks like a useful hook for other purposes also - e.g. I've got a custom price multiplier (membership x chapters) and bulk discount option, thanks. Also - you might consider packaging this up in an extension?

Comment: Would this need to be a custom CiviCRM extension or would it largely work in a Drupal or Backdrop module instead? Just curious as I feel a bit more at home there and usually have a custom module for minor tweaks like this. I just don't know if a CiviCRM hook will get triggered if it's in a Drupal module...

Comment: Yes - CiviCRM hooks get triggered when they are in a Drupal module! I often go that route for the exact same reason.